# Drawers opens by default in react native

Tags: react-native

I am making a react native app which contains two navigator like below.

```
const drawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
    {
        HomePage: { screen: Stack },
        History: { screen: History },
        Transactions: { screen: Transactions },
        Profile: { screen: EditProfile },
        Wallet: { screen: Wallet },
        ResetPassword: { screen: ResetPassword }
    },
    {
        contentComponent: props => <Drawer { ...props }
/>;
},
{
    contentOptions: {
        activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
    }
});

const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
    Splash: { screen: Splash },
    Login: { screen: Login },
    Register: { screen: Register },
    ForgotPassword: { screen: ForgotPassword },
    CreateProfile: { screen: CreateProfile },
    UploadDocuments: { screen: UploadDocuments },
    Home: { screen: drawerNavigator }
}, {
    headerMode: 'none',
    initialRouteName: 'Splash'
});
```

Now the problem is that when i logged in successfully then in goes to drawernavigator like this.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Home")
```

But the problem is that when it goes in stack then it opens drawer by default.How can i make drawer close by default in react native

Comment: did you find a solution? i have exactly the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54904169/drawers-opens-by-default-in-react-native#comment96577418_54904696

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that there are 2 routes with name 'Home', one in RootStack and one in drawerNavigator

so every time you navigate to 'Home' both routs get activated. Try changing the name in any one stack

**update for closing drawer

```
const parent = this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent();
const isDrawerOpen = parent && parent.state && parent.state.isDrawerOpen;

if(isDrawerOpen)
this.props.navigation.closeDrawer();
```

put this in your componentDidMount()

**for showing data from async storage i did this

```
class homeDrawerComponent  extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            user: null
        };
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        let user = await appDataStorage.getUser();
        await this.setState({ user: user });
  }

  render(){

    const name = this.state.user?this.state.user.firstName+' '+this.state.user.lastName:'';
    const email = this.state.user?this.state.user.email:'';

    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View
          style={{ height: height * .22, justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'flex-start', backgroundColor: 'white',paddingLeft:10,paddingTop:10 }} >
          <Image
            source={require('./components/images/sj-book-library-logo-drawer.png')}
            style={{ width: width * .22, height: width * .25, borderRadius: 50 }} />
            <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#0094FFFF' }}>
              {name}
            </Text>
          <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#0094FFFF' }}>
            {email}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <ScrollView>
          <DrawerItems {...this.props} />
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Changed but problem remains

Comment: for which stack you changed?

Comment: changed drawer navigator name from Home to HomePage

Comment: i have one more issue can u help me.the drawer header contains text with name and age.now after successful login i am storing both in asyncstorage and in drawer component inside componentdidupdate() i fetch from asyncstorage and set text data using this.setStata but that also doesnt works

Comment: you can try to close the drawer in componentDidMount() if it is open

Comment: in componentdidmount i have already added a line i.e. this.props.navigation.closeDrawer()

Comment: still it is coming ?

Comment: ye brother and by default opened drawer doesn not  setstate the name on drawer.I have to close app then it render in drawer

Comment: sorry i dnt know anything about this,may be try to  reset cache with `react-native run-android -- --reset-cache`